# Empty Render Layers node in Compositor

Tags: rendering, node-editor, compositing-nodes, render-layers

I was trying to make some adjustments in compositing, but Render Layers are not showing anything. In the UV Editor "Render Result" is correct. Re-rendering scene from Render Layers node doesn't help. I have Compositing option on, and Sequencer off. I was searching for solution since long time, but I couldn't find out anything which can help here...[image]

Comment: Check "Use Nodes" in the top of your compositing work space

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help either... I solved this by coping everything to new file and make new render settings. But still I don't know what caused this.

Comment: I had the same problem. Copying to new file is the only thing that works.